# Change open weather icons

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, openweathermap

Please help! 
In MVC 5 project I need to change default icons(eg "icon":"01d") from JSON response of open weather api, on custom icons: [weather icons](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/).
Any ideas?

Comment: JSON response? default Icon? I'm afraid I don't quite understand, are you saying you want to use and set an icon from the weather icons repository?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) . And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the library in your MVC project. For Install follow the steps below
1. Right click on Solution Explorer, then click on "Manage Nuget Packages".
2. In browser type "weather icons". Then click on install.
3. After installing add this script to your bundles files.
that's it call the icons where you want